# how to make php auto page number count?

Tags: php, count, numbers

I'm currently using this code which will force me to keep adding page number line code.

```
<div align="center"><font size="6">Page: </font> <?php
if (strpos($so, "1")) echo $_SESSION['config']['page']==1 ? '<a href="?page=1"><b><font color="red" size="6">[1]</font></b></a> ' : '<a href="?page=1"><font size="5">[1]</font></a> ';

if (strpos($so, "2")) echo $_SESSION['config']['page']==2 ? '<a href="?page=2"><b><font color="red" size="6">[2]</font></b></a> ' : '<a href="?page=2"><font size="5">[2]</font></a> ';
?> </div>
```

my question is if its possible to make a simple code to just count and add pages ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div align="center"><font size="6">Page: </font>
<?php
for($i=1;$i<10;$i++) {
    if (strpos($so, $i)) echo $_SESSION['config']['page']==$i ? '<a href="?page='.$i.'"><b><font color="red" size="6">['.$i.']</font></b></a> ' : '<a href="?page='.$i.'"><font size="5">['.$i.']</font></a> ';
}
?>
</div>
```

Do you mean something like this?

Comment: the loop works fine for me, if there's an error the problem must be in your code

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. What you need to know is how many pages you need to list, and which is selected. You could store these in a variable in a number of different ways (i've kept it simple below). Then you can just loop to display the page options:

```
$pages = 6;        // number of pages to show
$current_page = 3; // to highlight selected page
```

Now for actually outputting the values into HTML.

```
<ol id="pagination">
    <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++): ?>
    <li <?php if ($i === $current_page): ?>class="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
        <a href="?page=<?php echo $i; ?>">[<?php echo $i; ?>]</a>
    </li>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</ol>
```

I've separated the style from the HTML (you can add your font-size and whatever else here too):

```
#pagination .selected {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply and i'm sure it's ok, but i can't get it to work, please note that the data is fitched using curl from another site.
thanks

Comment: No worries - I've answered the best I could with the information you've provided in the quesion.